# Which longitude/latitude adjustments do I need to enlarge my map to the northwest and to the southeast?

Tags: c#, geolocation, geospatial, latitude-longitude, bing-maps

This is related to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937358/can-i-adjust-my-bing-maps-view-locationrect-bounding-box-by-a-small-amount)

I want to add a "shim" to my map so that the extreme pushpins aren't half-in bounds, half out-of-bounds. I'm on the right track (no pun intended), but my logic is faulty. I wrote this method:

```
// Adapted from Brundritt and Boonaert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937358/can-i-adjust-my-bing-maps-view-locationrect-bounding-box-by-a-small-amount
public static Location GetAShimLocation(IList<Location> locations, bool IsForNorthwestCorner)
{
    const double MAP_CUSHION = 0.1; // Is this a comfortable enough cushion?
    // I don't know why the Lats are 85 instead of 90
    double maxLat = -85;
    double minLat = 85;
    double maxLon = -180;
    double minLon = 180;

    foreach (Location loc in locations)
    {
        if (loc.Latitude > maxLat)
        {
            maxLat = loc.Latitude;
        }

        if (loc.Latitude < minLat)
        {
            minLat = loc.Latitude;
        }

        if (loc.Longitude > maxLon)
        {
            maxLon = loc.Longitude;
        }

        if (loc.Longitude < minLon)
        {
            minLon = loc.Longitude;
        }
    }
    Location retLoc = new Location();
    // I'm not sure this math is right - test it later
    if (IsForNorthwestCorner)
    {
        retLoc.Latitude = maxLat - MAP_CUSHION;
        retLoc.Longitude = maxLon - MAP_CUSHION;
    }
    else // SouthEast corner - stretch a little both directions
    {
        retLoc.Latitude = minLat + MAP_CUSHION;
        retLoc.Longitude = minLon + MAP_CUSHION;
    }
    return retLoc;
}
```

...and call it like so:

```
private void ResizeMap()
{         
    App.photosetLocationCollection.Add(
        PhotraxUtils.GetAShimLocation(App.photosetLocationCollection, true));            
    App.photosetLocationCollection.Add(
        PhotraxUtils.GetAShimLocation(App.photosetLocationCollection, false));
    photraxMap.SetView(new LocationRect(App.photosetLocationCollection));
}
```

...and it *does* alter the size of the map without adding the "shim" locations as pushpins, but instead of pulling the map up a little north and west, and also south and east, it seems to be squashing it vertically (reducing latitude scope) and stretching it horizontally (increasing longitude).

What combination of min and max and minus and plus do I really need here?

To sum up: what I'm looking for is to "stretch" the map a little further northwest from the northwest corner and a little further southeast from the southeast corner.

A 50-point (or more) after-the-fact bounty to whoever figures this out.

### UPDATE

Here it is after incorporating Jan Kukacka's code, and playing around with the cushion until I found what was about right; YMMV (no pun intended).

```
public static Location GetAShimLocation(IList<Location> locations, bool IsForNorthwestCorner)
{
    const double MAP_CUSHION = 1.05; // This seems to be about perfect
    //double maxLat = -85; <= This is what the original (ad[a,o]pted) code was, I don't know why 85 instead of 90, though
    //double minLat = 85;
    double maxLat = -90;
    double minLat = 90;
    double maxLon = -180;
    double minLon = 180;

    foreach (Location loc in locations)
    {
        if (loc.Latitude > maxLat)
        {
            maxLat = loc.Latitude;
        }

        if (loc.Latitude < minLat)
        {
            minLat = loc.Latitude;
        }

        if (loc.Longitude > maxLon)
        {
            maxLon = loc.Longitude;
        }

        if (loc.Longitude < minLon)
        {
            minLon = loc.Longitude;
        }
    }
    Location retLoc = new Location();

    double latDif = Math.Abs(maxLat - minLat);
    double lonDif = Math.Abs(maxLon - minLon);
    // This logic from Jan Kukacka https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948104/which-longitude-latitude-adjustments-do-i-need-to-enlarge-my-map-to-the-northwes
    if (IsForNorthwestCorner)
    {
        retLoc.Latitude = maxLat - MAP_CUSHION * latDif;
        retLoc.Longitude = maxLon - MAP_CUSHION * lonDif;
    }
    else // SouthEast corner - stretch a little both directions
    {
        retLoc.Latitude = minLat + MAP_CUSHION * latDif;
        retLoc.Longitude = minLon + MAP_CUSHION * lonDif;
    }
    // Edge case insurance
    if (retLoc.Latitude > 90.0)
    {
        retLoc.Latitude = 90.0;
    }
    else if (retLoc.Latitude < -90.0)
    {
        retLoc.Latitude = -90.0;
    }

    if (retLoc.Longitude > 180.0)
    {
        retLoc.Latitude = 180.0;
    }
    else if (retLoc.Longitude < -180.0)
    {
        retLoc.Longitude = -180.0;
    }
    return retLoc;
}
```

Comment: :Where is the bounty? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can only set a bounty on a question after it's been languishing for a couple of days, so I can't set it up yet. But after the fact, I will ("reward an existing answer"). So, provided there is a workable answer, I will bountify the question in two days, and then award the bounty one day after that (there's a "cooling off period" for awarding bounties). I'm hoping there are some skilled bounty hunters out there!

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to move your pins to an incorrect location, so that they are in view -- seeing as you obviously can't extend the map beyond [-180, 90], [180, -90]. I understand that this is not to send cats to the moon, as you brilliantly put it, so you are looking for a scale-dependent way to move the pins just enough, that they are fully in view?

Comment: I don't want bogus pushpins (then the user would tap them and be disappointed and/or mad at me) but bogus locations, one to the northwest, one to the southeast. And yes, so that the pushpins are fully, not partially, visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how does your map look "squashed", nevertheless your cushion should be relatively sized, eg. 10% of the map size. Try something like this:

```
 double latDif = Math.Abs(maxLat - minLat);
 double lonDif = Math.Abs(maxLon - minLon);
 if (IsForNorthwestCorner)
 {
     retLoc.Latitude = maxLat - MAP_CUSHION * latDif;
     retLoc.Longitude = maxLon - MAP_CUSHION * lonDif;
 }
 else // SouthEast corner - stretch a little both directions
 {
     retLoc.Latitude = minLat + MAP_CUSHION * latDif;
     retLoc.Longitude = minLon + MAP_CUSHION * lonDif;
 }
```

Comment: See the screamshot here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937358/can-i-adjust-my-bing-maps-view-locationrect-bounding-box-by-a-small-amount to see what I mean - there are pushpins at the top and bottom of the map that are "riding the fence"

Comment: I'll czech this out when I get home and can test it; if it works, I'll gladly give you the bounty (of course, I may have to adjust my MapCusion value). And if I ever get back to Prague, I'll buy you a pint of Pilsner Urquell on tap (AKA the nectar of the humans).

Comment: Thanks; will award the bounty ASAP (14 hours); see my update for the new code.

Answer (score 1):

The radius of the earth at equator = 6,371 km. The equator is divided into 360 degrees of longitude, so each degree at the equator represents approximately 111.32 km. Moving away from the equator towards a pole this distance decreases to zero at the pole.To calculate the distance at different latitudes multiply it by the cosine of the latitude

3 decimal places,0.001 degrees aproximates to 111.32 meters at equator
96.41meters at 30 degrees N/S
78.71 meters at 45 degrees N/S
55.66 meters at 60 degrees N/S
28.82 meters at 75 degrees N/S

This means that adding a fixed value to longitude is wrong. This value will require to be reduced as the point move towards the poles.

Given a start point, initial bearing, and distance, this formula will calculate the destination point and final bearing travelling along a (shortest distance) great circle arc. 
[**See**](http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/calculation.html)for explanation.
Given your start point you find the new location by projecting 45degrees from each of your points,

var R = 6371 km 3,960miles
lat/lng in radians
d in kms/miles

I show javascript formula as don't use C#.

JavaScript: formula:    (all angles in radians)

```
var lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng));
var lng2 = lng1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

Comment: @davidstrachnan:Isn't that a problem with the linear transformation, i.e. map size? I don't think your solution is working!?

Comment: @davidstrachnan: I don't need it super-precise; basically what I need to know is: In my code, where do I need to use minLat, maxLat, minLon, and MaxLon; also, do I need to add or subtract for them my "cushion"; I can play around with the cushion to make sure it's enough but not too much no matter where in the world it is. Again: this app isn't for sending cats to the moon, just for making sure that otherwise only partially visible pushpins are completely visible.